Identifying a couple serial killer movie, involving kids
I remember this one scene where this kid is locked in a house, and he breaks free, gets to a bathroom, and identifies the address based on pill bottles in the bathroom. As the woman breaks in the door, they're met with the serial killers (Who seem like a normal couple). She ends up finding the boy locked in a body bag, (Or something air tight), save him, and eventually find in their closets a bunch of tapes documenting the couples other murder.
This was a color movie, english language, made at least 5 years ago, but is a more recent movie (so roughly 2005 - 2012).
What movie was this?

We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Did you happen to ask this question b4? I answered twice b4 (months ago) and both questions were closed and deleted.

No @madmada, not that I can remember. Curious why this got so many downvotes, I tried searching for hours, and figured this scene was unique enough to be identified (Which it was, thanks madmada).

It's indeed unique enough, but there's some strict rules (and some dislike by some) regarding id question here. Usually you're advised to add as many details as possible and language, year, etc (which I see you tried to). Anyway don't take those downvotes personal and just add as many details as possible in future questions to avoid them.

@madmada Tagging you, posted a meta about this here.

That's a scene from Running Scared 2006
Here it is,



